# Generate header dynamically to display requested file

Tags: php

I have a folder with many files of different types. I need to display any requested file, so the header has to be adapted accordingly. What I tried is:

```
header( 'Content-Type: ' . filetype( 'files/' . $file ) );

readfile( 'files/' . $file );
```

It works for JPG, PNG and GIF files, but for some reason MP3 files already crash the browser, so I suppose it doesn't work for every file type. Is there something wrong with the approach, or the code? How would you do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/filetype1), `filetype()` *Returns the type of the file. Possible values are fifo, char, dir, block, link, file, socket and unknown.*

What you want is the MIME type of the file.  What you want is [Fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).  For example:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
header("Content-Type: ".finfo_file($finfo, 'files/'.$file));
finfo_close($finfo);
readfile('files/'.$file);
```

You can also quickly try [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), if available, just to make sure there is nothing else wrong with the system.  But this is not recommended because **it is depricated**.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the correct mime type and that can be tricky.

You can use the [mime-content-type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function, but that is a **deprecated** function.

```
$mimetype = mime_content_type ( $file );
header( 'Content-type: '. $mimetype );
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for mp3 files

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```